# EventHandler with Task as return value

Tags: c#

The base C# `EventHandler` is defined as:

```
namespace System
{
    public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
}
```

Does anyone if there is an awaitable event handler available? E.g.

```
public delegate Task EventHandlerAsnyc<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

Thx

Comment: Not built into .NET, no, but you can add one yourself, though that would (should) also make the `OnEventName` method return a task as well and would force you to write code up the stack async "to do it properly". Can I ask instead what you hope having this delegate would solve for you?

Comment: No, but please explain what you need this for. If you simply want an (eg. winforms) event to be processed `async`, you can declare the handler as `async void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. This is one of the rare (if not only) case where `void` as return type of an `async` method is ok to use.

Comment: @RenéVogt your comment re the `async void` event handler is the answer . You could even cite one of the many articles stating as such. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @RenéVogt, thx for the comment, as NKosi stated that answers my question. Can you add your comment as answer to this question? Thx

Comment: That would be a rather horrible design bug.  Events can have multiple subscribers, which return value are you going to use?  They are an impedance mismatch, async void event handlers are okayish when they are UI related events.  Some of them anyway.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want your event to be processed `async` (meaning you can use `await` to return early and resume later) you can simply declare the handler as `async void`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
    }

    public async void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myButton.Enabled = false;

        await SomeAsyncOrLongRunningOnAnotherThreadTask();

        myButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This way `SomeAsyncOrLongRunningOnAnotherThreadTask()` won't block your UI thread. And the handler is resumed after that task completes.

---

Side note: normally `async` methods should always return a `Task` or `Task<T>` that can be `await`ed or otherwise handled by the caller. The use case above is (afaik) the only justified case where `void` should be used for an `async` method.

Answer (score 3):

The downside of just using `async void` handlers is that there is no way for the caller to wait for the result. This may be an issue for some interactive event handlers, like the ones using `CancelEventArgs`.

But you can still declare a `Task`-returning delegate type, if you wish. You just have to be careful how you raise it then. For instance, you could make an extension method which you can call as `handler.Raise(sender, EventArgs.Empty)`.

```
public delegate Task EventHandlerAsnyc<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs);

public static async Task Raise<TEventArgs>(this EventHandlerAsnyc<TEventArgs> handlers, object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (handlers == null)
        return;

    foreach (var handler in handlers.GetInvocationList())
        await ((EventHandlerAsnyc<TEventArgs>)handler).Invoke(sender, eventArgs);
}
```

Alternatively, you can allow handlers to execute concurrently. But this would probably be a bad idea unless well-documented, as it's probably considered surprising behavior.

```
public static Task RaiseAllowConcurrent<TEventArgs>(this EventHandlerAsnyc<TEventArgs> handlers, object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (handlers == null)
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    var invocationList = handlers.GetInvocationList();
    var tasks = new Task[invocationList.Length];

    for (var i = 0; i < invocationList.Length; ++i)
        tasks[i] = ((EventHandlerAsnyc<TEventArgs>)invocationList[i]).Invoke(sender, eventArgs);

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```